# "next" page problem with Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator in the last page

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-livewire

I am trying to use **Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator** to paginate a Laravel Collection within a Livewire component in the following way:

```
    public function render(): Factory|View|Application
    {
        $perPage = 3;
        $items = $this->myCollection->forPage($this->page, $perPage);
        $paginator = new Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($items, $this->myCollection->count(), $perPage, $this->page);

        return view('livewire.listing', [
            'paginatedMyCollection' => $paginator,
        ]);
    }
```

and in the **listing.blade.php**:

```
@foreach ($paginatedMyCollection as $element)
    @livewire('row', ['element' => $element], key($element->id))
@endforeach
{{ $paginatedMyCollection->links() }}
```

**It works fine(*)!** for example:

[image]

except when the last page of the collection is reached. In this case, the «next page» button is erroneously constructed, resulting in the following presentation:

[image]

I have checked the Illuminate package and it seems that instead of using `'pagination.next'` is taking this `'Showing.next'` that does not work.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks and regards.

(*) The small buttons at the beginning and end of the page numbers could be filled with any character...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is CSS issue.
Laravel Pagination is using tailwind per default.

If you are using Bootstrap, you can add Paginator::useBootstrapFive(); in app\Providers\AppServiceProvider boot() function

I am not sure how many libraries is supported, but you can always publish vendor view for pagination and edit it

**php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination**

Comment: Thank you very much Ademir. I have followed your suggestions but I get no change. I included Paginator::useBootstrapFive(); in AppServiceProvider > boot(), I published the resources, and I begin to change the 'pagination.next' labels in all the versions: bootstrap-5.blade.php, simple-bootstrap-5.blade.php, default.blade.php, simple-default.blade.php, tailwind.blade.php, simple-tailwind.blade.php, semantic-ui.blade.php... to be sure that it was not taking a default version, but it seemed that it was taking this values from elsewhere, as it never changed. I must be missing something...

Comment: If that's the case, please see https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/pagination#custom-pagination-view

Comment: Yes, I uses that documentation to install the pagination but I don’t see there any clue to solve the problem. Thank you very much for your interest! 